# JSON encoding in Eclipse using Maven

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven, utf-8

How can I use Maven `pom.xml` in my project so that Eclipse plug-in can automatically set the JSON encoding to `UTF-8`?

The default seems to be locally referenced. I tried the source property but doesn't work.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

This is the configuration I want to change using pom.xml configuration:

[image]

Comment: Pom configuration is not your Eclipse configuration. Pom configuration affect the targeted project. You have to change your properties file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pom configuration is not your Eclipse configuration. Pom configuration affect the targeted project. You have to change your properties file instead.